Residuals of my GLM does not meet the homogeneity of variance assumption
I have ran several generalized linear models on a numeric dependent variable that is likely not normally distributed. I haven't taken ever option available to me so far, but all my models state that the Levene test for homogeneity of variance is significant so before I go through a multi-day battle with my analysis I wanted to check in with you all about possible solutions and the importance of homogeneity.
My dependent variable (body-phosphorus content) is numeric and continuous, my factors are fixed. One factor is binary (diet) and the other is 3 categorical units (reproductive output) - 2 of the units are the same samples but different values. To be more specific about the categorical factor, I have snails that were not reproductive, snails that were reproductive without their brood mass, and snails that were reproductive with their brood mass. The snails that were reproductive are the same snails but their values are different because of the inclusion or exclusion of the brood mass. I described my categorical variable in-depth because I believe it might be linear. I can best describe it as multicollinear but I am describing similarity within the factor and not across factors.

I made a histogram (using ggplot:geom_histogram) of the dependent variable to see its distribution. My data did not look normal.


I tried to figure out what distribution may describe my data the best so I plotted different distributions I think my data fits using fitdistrplus. Please let me know if fitrdistrplus allows me to plot Tweedie distributions!





I run several generalized linear models with a (using glmmTMB). I plotted the residuals of the model using DHARMa::simulateResiduals. I found that gamma distribution with log link seemed to meet most of the assumptions, but not the homogeneity of variance. I did not use weibull distribution because glmmTMB does not have that distribution available but please let me know if I am wrong!

Here is my code modified for clarity:
library("glmmTMB") mod <- glmmTMB(body-phosphorus_content ~ diet*Reproductive_output, data = data, family = "Gamma") summary(mod)
library("DHARMa") sim <- simulateResiduals(mod) plot(sim) plotResiduals(sim, data$Reproductive_output) plotResiduals(sim, data$diet)



And log-normal distribution:



Here I noticed that my residuals never met the assumption of the homogeneity of variance, specifically the residuals of my categorical independent variable.
So after trying to find a distribution that best fits my data I decided that I should transform my data for it to fit any distribution. I first transformed my data: squared, cubed, and inverse, but none of them followed a normal distribution. Log and square-root trasnformed data did look somewhat normal.
Log:

Square root:

However, when I ran both of them through a general linear model, again Levene test was significant.
Log:



Square-root:



So now I am wondering - could there be an unexpected effect of using the same samples for 2 categories? If there is - how can I reorganize my data to address this? How important is it that the variance of my data are homogenous - is it so important that I should spend more time figuring this out or simply report this as a caveat in my manuscript?
Thank you for any help!

What is your research question? Do your data have a nesting structure that made you want to use a generalized linear mixed model (i.e., as implemented in glmmTMB)? What specific model did you fit?

@Noah. Thank you for the response! I will add the code of my model to the question. My research question is how does diet (binary) and reproductive status (reproductive w/ brood v. reproductive wo/ brood, and non-brooding) affect body-phosphorus content?

@Noah There is no nesting or random factors. I usually do have random factors or nesting components in my models so I usually use glmmTMB. I just stuck with glmmTMB because I am use to it.

My humble suggestion: Since you are using glmmmTMB, have you tried to model the dispersion? I mean, using the dispformula argument, you can model the heteroscedasticity, including the variable reproductive_output, and evaluate the model.

Thank you so much! This worked with the current models that I am using. New code:  mod <- glmmTMB(body-phosphorus_content ~ diet*Reproductive_output, data = data, family = "Gamma", dispformula = ~ Reproductive_output)
My DHARMA diagnostics show that my model meets the assumption of heteroskedasticity with this model! My results from summary(mod) show that Reproductive_output for BwoE or Bwe have a p values of 0.190 and 0.373 so I think Reproductive_output does not affect the variance of body-phosphorus_content. So I will be going forward with this method. Thank you again!

Thank you so much! New code:  mod <- glmmTMB(body-phosphorus_content ~ diet*Reproductive_output, data = data, family = "Gamma", dispformula = ~ Reproductive_output)
My DHARMA diagnostics show that my model meets the assumption of heteroskedasticity with this model! My results from summary(mod) show that Reproductive_output for BwoE or Bwe have a p values of 0.190 and 0.373. Since I included the dispersion model as  ~ Reproductive_output it no longer affects the variance of body-phosphorus_content. So I will be going forward with this method. Thank you again!

Your dependent variable does not have to be normal to use linear regression, and the residuals do not have to be homoscedastic. The assumption required for usual normal-theory inference is that the residuals are normally distributed, not the outcome. Regardless, there are methods of inference that are robust to these features in most cases, especially in larger samples. For example, you can bootstrap the standard errors or use a robust variance estimator.
Running a battery of tests on your data and making modeling decisions after looking at distributions and running tests invalidates your inferences. Although it can be a good idea to check the validity of your assumptions, checking assumptions and performing inference in the same dataset means you are adding in uncertainty that is not accounted for by the standard errors. Indeed, it is possible that the data-dredging you are doing by fitting multiple models and making choices based on the results of tests is worse for inference than a robust approximation that you could have used prior to running these tests.
If you are truly concerned about the distribution of your outcome variable, use a semiparametric model like ordinal logistic regression. This makes weaker assumptions than a parametric model with little cost in precision. rms::orm() provides a nice interface to this model. I would recommend bootstrapping all inferences; this massively relaxes assumptions on the distributions. There are ways of computing confidence intervals using bootstrapping that have good robustness and coverage properties, like the bias-correct and accelerated (BCa) bootstrap.

Thank you for your response! I have had a couple of days to think about this. It seems I have misunderstood some things, and I want to be sure what I am doing makes sense. 1. I am not concerned about the values of my dependent variable distribution, but I do use the distribution of dependent variable to choose the appropriate model. 2. Why can the model residuals be heteroscedastic? Why can that assumption be broken? 3. If I compare the AICs of my models will that account for standard errors? 4. I have not bootstrapped before but I would be interested in it. Do you have any sources?
